# Creating a link between IOS Apps

Tags: ios, image, message

China has a messaging App, The App is call Wechat 微信 with 300 millions users.
With WeChat, you can link to other e-commerce App and the e-commerce App can send pictures to WeChat?

How does linking to another app like this work? As far as i know, ios does not support that.

Comment: What makes you think it is iOS that is doing it?  My guess is that messaging server takes care of it.  Or do you mean it sends it between them on the same device?  In that case they are definitely using **URL Schemes** (look it up)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**URL Schemes** may help..

Here is [Apple Document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Here is [tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/)

Answer (score 2):

I do it like this:

```
// See developer's Weixin
NSURL *wxurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"weixin://contacts/profile/fulldecent"];
NSURL *backupurl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://user.qzone.qq.com/858772059"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: wxurl]){
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:wxurl];
} else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:backupurl];
}
```

So it works even if WX is not installed

Comment: If you know how I can link directly to the WX user profile online, please let me know